# Is there any cocoapods, npm, git.io, etc alternative for android studio (1.4.1)?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I would love to know if theres a fast way (some kind of tool) to install libraries or frameworks on Android studio, like there is on iOS, appcelerator, node etc...!

I saw someone talking about gradle but I'm not aware of some kind of `gradle install` (or something) command to install any libraries.

Am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: You don't "install libraries or frameworks on Android studio". You add dependencies to your project; the build system then will "install libraries or frameworks" based on that list. The build system used by default for Android Studio is Gradle, and so, by default, Gradle will be the one to download the "libraries or frameworks" and add them to your project at build time. This is covered in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#buildFileBasics).

Comment: Even when Gradle installed a dependency for me (skobbler library), I still cant import it, eventhough I can see it listed on my packages below `com.skobbler....` when I type `import com.skobbler.ngx` I get an error. pff

Comment: I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you post your Gradle build files, plus your source code and the exact text of the error, and perhaps somebody can point out where you are going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll do that.